# Images are not saved into the photo_dir folder using cakephp-upload plugin on CakePHP 3.2

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, image-uploading

I am using the [cakephp-upload plugin](https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-upload) and I managed to upload images to my server:

**WorkersTable:**

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->table('workers');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');

    $this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
        'avatar' => [
            'fields' => [
                'dir' => 'photo_dir'
            ]
        ]
    ]);
}
```

**view.ctp:**

```
echo $this->Form->create($newWorker, ['type' => 'file']);
echo $this->Form->input('avatar', ['type' => 'file']);
echo $this->Form->input('photo_dir', ['type' => 'hidden']);
```

Now the avatar images are uploaded, but they are not put into the photo_dir subdirectory.

[image]

What am I missing? It works without any problems in my CakePHP 2.8.x application.

Comment: does the photo_dir actually exist on the server?

Comment: `photo_dir` is a column in the workers table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Author of the plugin here.

The `fields.dir` attribute does not state what the subdirectory should be. It is a reference to the column in your database table where we should save the `director` where we saved the file.

If you want to change the place where you save files on disk, you should instead use the `path` option. Here is an example where i use the `photo_dir` subdirectory:

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
    'avatar' => [
        'path' => 'webroot{DS}files{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}photo_dir{DS}'
    ]
]);
```

The default value for the `path` option is `webroot{DS}files{DS}{model}{DS}{field}{DS}`.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it be:

```
$this->addBehavior('Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload', [
     'avatar' => [
         'fields' => [
             'dir' => 'avatar_dir'
         ]
     ]
 ]);

echo $this->Form->input('avatar_dir', ['type' => 'hidden']);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use better option than you can use below plugin which has better option for upload the file rather than `Josegonzalez/Upload.Upload` plugin.

I have used below one in my project.

```
Utils Plugin for Cake 3.x
```

Link for this plugin : https://github.com/cakemanager/cakephp-utils

Documentation : http://cakemanager.org/docs/utils/1.0/behaviors/uploadable/

And this is the configuration :

```
$this->addBehavior('Utils.Uploadable', [
            'image' => [
                'path' => '{ROOT}{DS}{WEBROOT}{DS}uploads{DS}{field}{DS}',
                'fileName' => md5(rand(1000, 5000000)) . '.{extension}',
                'removeFileOnDelete' => true,
                'removeFileOnUpdate' => FALSE
            ],
        ]);
```

Here you can customise it. Let me know if you have any question regarding this.

Comment: Did you try this solution ?